# MongoDB Java wrong Driver

Tags: java, linux, mongodb

i got a problem with MongoDB. I installed it on my linux server with sudo apt-get install mongodb. When i now try to connect with my java driver to it, it says

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoIncompatibleDriverException: This version
>   of the driver is not compatible with one or more of the servers to
>   which it is connected: ClusterDescription{type=STANDALONE,
>   connectionMode=SINGLE,
>   serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017,
>   type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true,
>   version=ServerVersion{versionList=[2, 4, 10]}, minWireVersion=0,
>   maxWireVersion=0, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
>   roundTripTimeNanos=708358}]}

My mongodb version on the server semms to be older than my driver version.
My java driver version is 3.6
mongo-version shows me 2.4

How i could solve this problem ?

Comment: 3.6 was the newest for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default mongodb package for Ubuntu is (as of 2018) version 2.4. This is a fairly old version, not compatible with a 3.x client or java driver.

Judging from your question, I assume you're not committed to a legacy version, so you'll probably want to use version 3.x

This requires some more work than just typing apt install. You can follow the recipe on the MongoDB website:

https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

in case of you are using Docker to wrap your database, I suggest to change your ubuntu version to the 16.04LTS and then your mongod will install the 2.6.10 by default.

It's enough to run with java Driver, no need to get the 3.x.

here is Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq mongodb && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT mongod --dbpath /data/db --rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the old version:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mongodb-server
```

Then follow https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ to install the newest official version.

Comment: Problem has been solved. I installed mongodb with downloading the files and installing them manually.